# Balloon expansion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

I would like to do a calculation of an expanding balloon represented by a triangular spring-damper mesh system. Also the behavior of the balloon when it is put in a container, where its shape conform to the shape of the container while expanding. Can anybody point me to any studies being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper details the mathematical model behind what you are doing. By far the most difficult aspect is not the balloon itself but collisions with the environment:
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0407003

Comment: It helps a lot. Now I need to study more about collision handling. Thanks!